# Need help on Groovy Script

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to remove double quotes from the Value of 'version' but, not able to do that with the following groovy codes. Please help me resolving this.

- **Source JSON:**

  {"version":"1",
  "code":'',
  "eccQuoteExternalQuoteId":'100000136',
  "reasonForRejection":'',
  "rejectionCode":'',
  "state":{"code":'SOX_APP',"integrationKey":'Approve'},
  "integrationKey":''}

**Groovy Script:**

def Message processData(Message message) {

```
//Body 
def body = message.getBody(String.class);

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def list = jsonSlurper.parseText(body)

list.each{
    it.version=Integer.parseInt(it.get("version").toString().replace(" ",""));        
    }
def jsonOP = JsonOutput.toJson(list)
 message.setBody(jsonOP)
 return message;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
it.version=Integer.parseInt(it.get("version").toString().replace(" ",""));
```

with

```
it.version=it.get("version").toString().toInteger();
```

see the ref [toInteger](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#toInteger()).

Comment: Thanks mate.. getting following error  The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 23
{"version":"1", "code":'', "eccQuoteExternalQuoteId":'100000136', "reasonForRejection":'', "rejectionCode":'', "state":{"code":'SOX_APP',"integrationKey":'Approve'}, "integrationKey":''}
.......................^@ line 11 in script1.groovy

Comment: Your json is incorrect. For example `'SOX_APP'` and `'100000136'` quoted with single quotes. But in json only doublequotes could be used for strings. So error message is about that.

Comment: Thank you very much mate.. I got that and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is incorrect because there are single quotes used for some values. However you could try LAX parser to ignore this issue.

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX)
```

If the json from question is coming through the message body then just change

```
list.each{
    it.version=Integer.parseInt(it.get("version").toString().replace(" ",""));        
    }
```

To

```
list.version = list.version as Integer
```

Comment: Thanks .. getting below error ...The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 23
{"version":"1", "code":'', "eccQuoteExternalQuoteId":'100000136', "reasonForRejection":'', "rejectionCode":'', "state":{"code":'SOX_APP',"integrationKey":'Approve'}, "integrationKey":''}
.......................^@ line 11 in script1.groovy

Answer (score 0):

@daggett is right, you can do like he said.

It seems that the value of that object is a string, not a problem of quotes.
You can check the class of any the object with:

```
println(it.version.getClass())
```

if it's a string you can change it in various ways but if its a string you could simply use the below - I'm putting it in more lines just for better visibility but the result is the same as the inline from daggett

```
def newInt = it.version.toInteger()
it.version = newInt
```

There are other ways to do the same thing if you really need to convert it.

here a guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-convert-string-to-integer

Maybe changing the value from string to int in that class creating the JSON is the best way to go.